# In JQuery UI, how can I decrement the count as items are dragged between droppable areas?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript

I'm using JQuery UI 1.8.3, please see diagram below for my page setup.
I am counting the number of items dragged into droppable areas however the count is not correct when I drag an item out from A to B.  For example, if I drag item 1 to box A the count (#) for box A becomes 1, but then if I drag item 1 from A to B, the count for box A remains 1 but I need it to decrement to 0.

```
  +------------------------+      +-----------------------+
  | Items (Dragable items) |      | A (Droppable Area)  # |
  |------------------------|      |-----------------------|
  |  item 1                |      |                       |
  |  item 2                |      |                       |
  |  item ...              |      +-----------------------+
  |  item n                |
  |                        |      +-----------------------+
  |                        |      | B (Droppable Area)  # |
  |                        |      |-----------------------|
  |                        |      |                       |
  |                        |      |                       |
  +------------------------+      +-----------------------+
```

My code looks like this to drop items:

```
$(".dropArea").droppable({
    ...
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).append($(ui.draggable));

    // count the items in the box and update
    ...
}
```

What would be the correct way to decrement the box count when an item is dropped out of the box A or B?  Please let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each drop event, count the number of objects in each droppable area and update your counters.

Something like this would give you the count of objects:

```
$(".dropArea").each(function (index, elem) {
    $(item).find(".count").text($(this).find("div").size());
});
```

Comment: `size()` is deprecated use `length` instead per docs:  http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly.  But I imagine this could become slow if there are a lot of drop areas.  Do you know of any way to just update the area that had been dropped to and from?

Comment: Wire up the `out` event and keep track of which .dropArea that the drag starts from in a variable, i.e. `var dragFrom = $(this)`.  Then in the `drop` event, change the selector to `$(this)` to include recounting the current drop target, and then duplicate the lines to recount the `$(dragFrom)` variable.

Comment: The problem I've seen with the out event is it fires not just for the area an item is dragged from but also any others the user might hover over and hence the dragFrom variable is overwritten incorrectly.  Maybe I was doing it wrong :-s

Comment: Always set the value of `dragFrom` to null in the `drop` event and only set the `dragFrom` variable in the `out` event if the value of `dragFrom` is null.  That way only the first 'dragged from' object will set it.